# Rest File upload octet-stream uploaded file is corrupted

Tags: files, 8

I use rest to post upload file (no file_entity, but core file) following direction in https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1927648

In the app I use FileRider to get file binary for post body.

```
  reader.onload = () => {        
    let data = reader.result;
    let file_name = event.target.files[0].name;

    this.rest.postFile(uri, data, file_name).subscribe(res => {
      this.saved_file = res;
    });

  }

  reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[0]);
```

post uri

```
  let uri = `/file/upload/${entity_type_id}/${bundle}/${field_name}?_format=json`;
```

rest.postFile is

```
  postFile(uri: string, file: File, filename) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.api_endpoint}${uri}`, file, {
      headers: new HttpHeaders()
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream')
        // Content-Disposition:file;filename="example.txt"
        .set('Content-Disposition', `file;filename="${filename}"`)
        .set('api-key', this.api_key)
    });
  }
```

File is uploaded and saved in proper place set in bundle field. File object is properly set filename, mimetype, status, uri and saved in drupal. 
The file itself is saved with a proper filename, size, mimetype application/octet-stream which cause system it is corrupted.

```
  $ file -i file-name.png 
  file-name.png: application/octet-stream; charset=binary
```

The same is for .docx, .pdf, .txt, .jpg - all files are uploaded, saved and attached to node (and changes staus to true), but they are corrupted - $ file -i show filename.png: application/octet-stream; charset=binary

What also I miss?

Environment:

xubuntu-16.04 latest

Apache/2.4.34 (Ubuntu)

PHP Version 7.2.9-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 FPM/FastCGI

Drupal-8.5.6 patch applied 
https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/1927648?page=1#comment-12685734, patch link https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2018-07-13/1927648-581.patch

Answer (score 0):

All work as expected when 'data' is file = event.target.files[0]
No need of FileRider.